# Sending value to activity through another

Tags: java, android

I am working on an update for my Rock Paper Scissors game (I know it's a simple concept and has been done before but still), and the update includes massive changes in layouts and the programming.

So far I have Three working Activities; MainMenu, SinglePlayer, SettingsActivity

The way that things work currently is the user will change a setting (Background, Vibration, etc) inside the SettingsActivity, and when the user hits the Main Menu button it will bundle all values (float backgroundNumber, boolean Vibration) and will send it over to the MainMenu activity. The MainMenu will then unpackage the values and save them, so when the user opens SinglePlayer or any other activity it can send the appropriate values over to that activity.

The issue comes in when the user wants to reset the SinglePlayer score counter...

Here's what works: User presses "Reset Score" inside Settings -> User presses Main Menu button -> User open Single Player (Score resets and everything works fine)

Here's what doesn't work: User presses "Reset Score" inside Settings -> User presses Main Menu button -> User opens a different activity other that Single Player/exits app -> User goes back to main menu -> User goes into Single Player (Score does not reset)

The Main Menu saves all values other than the resetScore boolean (So the score counter doesn't get fed 'resetScore = true;' every time SinglePlayer gets opened).

I'm not trying to advertise but if you are having problems following my description, try following the steps provided above live with the app: https://play.google.com/apps/testing/com.simplegames.chris.rockpaperscissors20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be considered a "hack", but this helped me.

After pressing the "Reset Score" button the SinglePlayer Activity is immediately opened to reset the score and then sent back to the Settings Activity. It happens so quickly that it doesn't even look like it left the Settings Activity.

I would remove the question, but who knows... someone else (or me in the future) might need it?